# Gain bandwidth product for amplifier

Tags: transistors, amplifier, gain-bandwidth-product

If a question simply asked "What is the gain bandwidth product of this amplifier?"

[image]

And when I am trying to utilize the equation :

GBW = (Av)(BW)

I am unsure if I should utilize the voltage gain from the signal source to the output (Avs = Vo/Vs), that is, its including the voltage drop accounting for the source resistance, or if its simply asking for the Av = Vo/Vi.

Is there a absolute right/wrong, a normal convention, or is either method arguably correct since the question didn't specify?

Comment: I don't believe you count the signal's source impedance when you analyze an amplifier, unless that source impedance resistor is part of the amplifier. In this circuit, it does *not* look that way. So I'd consider \$A_v=\frac{V_o}{V_i}\$.

Comment: If the "source" resistance (1k) should be neglected - I ask myself why they have included it in the diagram. So - I think it should be considered.....unfortunately, it is a matter of interpretation....

Comment: Where's the input coupling capacitor?